# How to map the newly created records in parent table with the child table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016, stored-procedures, subquery

have a table

```
Employees

Id   Name   EmployeeType_ID

1    John        1
2.   Mathw       2


EmployeeTypes

Id   TypeName
1     Perm
2.    Temp
3.    Regular
```

Now I am copying data from one server to another for the same table i.e. Employees

```
Insert Into Employees
(
    Name, 
        EmployeeType_Id
)

Select 
Name, 
EmployeeType_Id 
from [192.xxx.xx.xx].EmployeesDb.dbo.Employees
where Id= @employeeId
```

Now, all is ok but problem started when the source db started adding EmployeeTypes e.g.

```
EmployeeTypes

Id   TypeName
1     Perm
2.    Temp
3.    Regular
4.    Visit
5.    Hourly
```

and started copying employees with these IDs

```
Employees

Id   Name   EmployeeType_ID

1    John        1
2.   Mathw       2
3.   Amy         4
4.   Ron         5
```

Now while performing this query on target db

```
Insert Into Employees
(
    Name, 
    EmployeeType_Id
)

Select 
Name, 
EmployeeType_Id 
from [192.xxx.xx.xx].EmployeesDb.dbo.Employees
where Id= @employeeId
```

Would copy the records but the `employeeType_Id` are not present on the target db since we assumed it will always be same but now users has started adding it.

One solution is came up with is to udpate the `EmployeeTypes` table every time on target before performing the above query.

```
INSERT INTO EmployeeTypes(
                        Name
                        ,EmployeeType_Id
                        
                        )
            SELECT  Name
                        EmployeeType_Id
                    FROM [192.xxx.xx.xx].EmployeesDb.dbo.EmployeeTypes cs
                    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                            SELECT 1
                            FROM EmployeeTypes ct
                            WHERE cs.Name = ct.Name)
                            )
```

It also works but sometimes it copies more than one records since users can add any number of records.

Now issue is how to map this newly created records with the employee records?

Note: Replication we cannot do; sql feature; we have to go with query.

Comment: Why can't you use a SQL Server feature, like replication? Also I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "*but sometimes it copies more than one records since users can add any number of records*", can you please elaborate?

Comment: hi, @J.D. thanks for replying. 

This code gets triggered when a user pres a button i.e. TRANSFER on UI otehrwise we don';t want to replicate or transfer other things.

Comment: means that see.. we have employee types on the server A which has 5 records and refereced in the Employees table then when we copy Employee data to Server B then it contains references to the EmployeeTypes which might not be present in the EmployeeTypes table in Server-B. So, I populate it everytime in Server-B for missing record using a query but the record it creates have different Ids. Now I want to replace the Ids reference by the Employee table that I copied by the Ids of EmployeeTypes that are created newly.

Comment: Got it. So your issue with your current solution is that the `Id`s that get generated don't always match between servers. You can turn [`IDENTITY_INSERT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-identity-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) on so you can copy over the exact `Ids` too. If this sounds like what you need, I'll add an answer with an example.

Comment: ah ok, i would be grateful if you post the example so I can take idea.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the code that maintain the `EmployeeTypes` you have shown ,
you can have a second step, that join the `EmployeeTypes` from source server with the same table from the target server , on the `TypeName` and get de right `id`

```
Insert Into Employees
(
    Name, 
    EmployeeType_Id
)
Select 
    e_Source.Name, 
    et_Target.Id 
from [192.xxx.xx.xx].EmployeesDb.dbo.Employees as e_Source
    INNER JOIN [192.xxx.xx.xx].EmployeesDb.dbo.EmployeeTypes as et_Source
        on e_Source.EmployeeType_Id  = et_Source.Id
    INNER JOIN dbo.EmployeeTypes as et_Target
        ON et_Source.TypeName = et_Target.TypeName
where Id= @employeeId
```

Comment: hi, thanks a lot. I will give it a try